# Counting number frequency with StringTokenizer

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

How can I use `StringTokenizer` to count how many times a number is present in a `String` if the numbers are separated with `"_"`? The `String` has to be entered through the command line.

For example if user enters:

```
1_3_34_12_1_2_34
```

the output will be

```
1_2, 3_1, 34_2, 2_1, 12_1
```

Comment: You can use a Map to store your number with their corresponding count..

Comment: I would use `split` rather than StringTokenizer.

Comment: does the output have to be presented in that <key><underscore><value> format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do

```
String input = "1_3_34_12_1_2_34";
String[] numbers = input.split("_");
Arrays.sort(numbers);
int count = -1;
String last = numbers[0];
for (String n : numbers) {
    count++;
    if (n.equals(last)) continue;
    System.out.print(last + '_' + count + ',');
    last = n;
    count = 0;
}
count++;
System.out.println(last + '_' + count);
```

prints

```
1_2,12_1,2_1,3_1,34_2
```

Hint: The order suggests you should use a `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>`

Comment: When I enter 1_1_1_1_1 it says 1_4. Even in your code 34 appears twice but output is 34_1. Whats wrong?

Comment: It forgot to count the last one.